# background image getResource not working Java

Tags: java, image, getresource

I think i am missing some understanding of the Java getResource() option. The following is my code and I am trying to set a background image.

My first approach is working, but for some reasons I need another way to do so.
That's why I tried getResource, but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.*;

public class AdventureTrails extends JFrame implements ActionListener { 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

    public AdventureTrails() {

        setTitle("AdventureTrails - Desktop-Application");
        setSize(1000,600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //working, but not what i want:
        setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/background.jpg")));

    //not working, but hopefully better if one of them does:
        setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("src/background.jpg"))));
        setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(AdventureTrails.class.getResource("src/background.jpg"))));
        setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/src/background.jpg"))));
        setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(AdventureTrails.class.getResource("/src/background.jpg"))));


        setSize(999,599);
        setSize(1000,600);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new AdventureTrails(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2433/resources-on-classpath#t=201701111734535687024&a=remarks .

Comment: thanks, but i could not get it working so far :/

Comment: Are you running from a .jar file?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: A .jar file is simply a zip file with a different filename extension.  Either use your IDE to examine its contents, or make a copy of the .jar file and rename it to end with .zip and use any zip tool (including the Windows explorer shell, if you like) to examine it.  Does it contain a `src/background.jpg` entry?

Comment: well, it contains an "AdventureTrails.class"-file and the "MANIFEST.MF" - thats is all. the class-file has exactly the code inside i wrote into my .java file.

But the AdventureTrails.jar file is placed in a folder which is called "bin", the backround.jpg is placed in a folder called "src". both of these folders are in the same directory "application".

Comment: You need to place your image inside the .jar file.  Until you do, `getResource` will not see it.

Comment: ah, alright! thats awesome! can i simply put a folder and an image inside?

Comment: It depends on how you are building your .jar file.  But, like I said, a .jar file is just a zip file with a different name, so it can have folder-like path entries just like a zip file can.

Comment: brilliant, thank you so much, it's working now :)